# How do I get return value (success or fail) when executing custom activities

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, custom-activity, databinding

I'm currently working custom activities on Journey Builder - however, I had troubles with getting response values after execution is done.

[Expected] 1. Journey Activates 2. Execute custom activity 3. When execution succeeds, return success 4. The journey moves to next steps when the activity succeed

[Now] 1. Journey Activates 2. Execute custom activity 3. When execution succeeds, return fails 4. The journey doesn't move to the next step when the activity succeed - it stuck in the same step.

It would be great if you give me a guide on how to send a response to Marketing Cloud.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/how-data-binding-works.htm
- I refer to this URL to build my custom activity.

If you need more information, please let me know at any time.

Thanks.

Comment: I've created some custom activities and for single path activities (does not split the path) we do return a 200 OK HTTP response, in Node.js + express: res.status(200).end();

Comment: Hi, @SebOB! Thanks for sharing. Then, have you ever experienced that REST activity failed? I think that journey stops when activity failed through executing. It would be great if you have any ideas to resolve the failed issue!

Comment: Can you not view the logs on the platform in which you are hosting the app? For instance, if hosting on Heroku, you should be able to dump errors to the log and then view them on Heroku. You need to handle your error reporting and responses on the application side rather than Marketing Cloud.

Comment: @JasonHanshaw Hi, thanks for your support. We are hosting the app in Java and using Servlet. However, our developer logged when there are errors in HTTP Response code. However, the current issue is REST API Error. Based on your suggestion, is it possible to log REST API Error as well? If it is possible for you, could you give me guide?